# When to flag as duplicate, and which one should I flag?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I asked [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17030/how-many-layers-should-be-in-a-mapservice-what-are-the-tradeoffs) a couple of weeks ago, and got a few answers, but haven't accepted one yet.

Today [a new question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17486/lots-of-layers-in-one-or-multiple-services-and-why) was asked that I'd consider a duplicate, but it goes into a lot more detail.  Right now it has no answers.

Should I

1. do nothing
2. flag the OP new question as a duplicate, even though it is asked in
   a better way.
3. flag my own question as a duplicate, and lose the somewhat helpful
   answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think "asked in a better way" is in the eye of the beholder.  (I haven't even been able to read entirely through the new question, it is so long and detailed.  Short, pithy, clear questions have a lot of merit, IMHO.)  Nevertheless, when an old (partially answered) question is re-asked in a way that elicits better answers or clarifies the previous one, we have the additional option of **merging** the two.  After a merge, the destination question remains intact, the source question disappears, but all answers and all comments to the source question appear beneath the destination question, sequenced as if they had been posted in the destination thread originally.  This could be extremely confusing if there's any essential difference between the two questions, so it is not done often.

Normally I would not consider merging an old question with a new one--it's almost always the other way around--but if the owner of the old one himself suggests it, then why not?  The flagging mechanism provides a (small) textbox for people to make such requests.